# Reading a file and going ahead only when the number of values in two lines are same

Tags: c

I'm trying a tackle a problem but I am not understanding how I can go about it. The task is as follows:

1. There is a txt file like this(1st number being the number of values to be worked with):

```
5 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5
5 5.5 4.4 3.3 2.2 1.1
2 0.1 -0.1
2 1 1
5 1 2 3 4 5
6 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And the output should be as follows:

```
6.6 6.6 6.6 6.6 6.6
1.1 0.9
Error(Number n1 != Number n2)
```

I am supposed to come up with a function read(file *fp, array[]) for reading the file, add(a1[], a2[], sum[]) to add numbers from two separate lines and output(sum[]) to give the result on the screen and call them in main(). The task is to add the values to their respective positions from the following line and if the number of elements aren't same, give an error.

I am thinking along the lines that I should read the first line as long as I don't reach '\n' and once reached, go to the next line and so on. But I am not able to write a function to read from the file. This is my attempt but I don't know how to move ahead.

```
float read(FILE *fp, float number[])    //For reading individual rows from txt file
{
    int count;
    if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) != 1) return -1;
    
    for(int i = 0; i != '\n'; ++i) {
        if(fscanf(fp, "%f", &number[i]) != 1) {
            return -1; 
        }
    }
    
    return number[0];
}
```

I'd be really grateful if someone could help with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `i` is a counter of the number of elements you're reading, it will never be equal to `'\n'`. You need `i < number` in the loop condition.

Comment: If you read with `fgets` and apply `sscanf` with the maximum expected item specifiers, and check the return value from `sscanf`, that will tell you when two lines have the same number of items.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's tricky because the maximum number is in the line.

Comment: @Barmar uh just convert the first item then.

Comment: @WeatherVane Without advanced features, it's hard to use `sscanf()` in a loop over the same string.

Comment: @Barmar I never suggested using a loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane How are you going to create a format string with a variable number of items in it? And then use it with a variable number of array elements to write into?

Comment: @Barmar I don't. I suggested using a format string with the maximum expected items. The example shows 5 so that would be `"%d%f%f%f%f%f"`. Of course if it is large...

Comment: @WeatherVane But if a line only has 2 items, you'll go too far.

Comment: Barmar I am using `fgets` and `sscanf`, not `fscanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, now I see. Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar I confess i originally missed the count at the start of each line.

Comment: What about fgets + loop + strtok + strtod? – First parameter parsed separately, of course...

Comment: caution, naming your function `read` as you suggest in your post will conflict with another function with the same name in the standard libraries.  Mybe use `my_read` or something else that is not part of C already.

Comment: Dangerous, too, is that you do not prevent (be it with fscanf or fgets + sscanf or anything else) scanning more elements than the array is able to hold (unless you are aware of a maximum that cannot ever get exceeded for whichever reason).

Answer (score 4):

> if someone could help with this.

**Algorithm**

1. Read an integer --> `n1`.
2. Allocate memory for `n1` numbers: `float sum[n1]`
3. In a loop, read rest of line into `sum[]`.
4. Read an integer --> `n2`.
5. If `n1 != n2`, print error, else in a loop (`n1` times), read an FP, sum with previous `sum[i]` and print.  Free memory either way.

---

Note: This approach does not well handle mal-formed input.  More advanced code needed to detect non-numeric input, scant/extra numbers per line, missing 2nd line, out-of-range number count, out of memory, [the usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSmfws0_To) ....

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to detect the newline because each line has the count of items. So just read that many items.

Yuo should read the first number into `count`, then use that as the limit of the loop. The return type of the function should then be `int`.

```
int read(FILE *fp, float number[])    //For reading individual rows from txt file
{
    int count;
    if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &count) != 1) return -1;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(fscanf(fp, "%f", &number[i]) != 1) {
            return -1; 
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an outside-the-box thinking approach?

Instead of forming an array to store the floating point data, use 2 file pointers to read the data.

Perhaps not quite what OP was looking for, yet it does avoid `float` memory management issues.

```
// Demonstrative code

// Return -1 on error,
// return 0 on number mis-match,
// else return 1
static int read_line_pair(FILE *f1, FILE *f2) {
  int n1, n2;

  fscanf(f2, "%*[^\n]");  // Skip line
  if (fscanf(f1, "%9d", &n1) != 1 || fscanf(f2, "%9d", &n2) != 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (n1 != n2) {
    printf("Error(Number %d != Number %d)\n", n1, n2);
    return 0;
  }
  while (n1 > 0) {
    n1--;
    double v1, v2;
    if (fscanf(f1, "%lf", &v1) != 1 || fscanf(f2, "%lf", &v2) != 1) {
      return -1;
    }
    printf("%g ", v1 + v2);
  }
  fscanf(f1, "%*1[\n]"); // Read trailing \n
  fscanf(f2, "%*1[\n]");

  fscanf(f1, "%*[^\n]");
  printf("\n");
  return 1;
}


int main() {
  const char *filename = "line_pairs.txt";
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
  assert(f);
  fprintf(f, // data
      "5 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5\n"
      "5 5.5 4.4 3.3 2.2 1.1\n"
      "2 0.1 -0.1\n"
      "2 1 1\n"
      "5 1 2 3 4 5\n"
      "6 1 2 3 4 5 6\n");
  fclose(f);

  FILE *f1 = fopen(filename, "r");
  assert(f1);
  FILE *f2 = fopen(filename, "r");
  assert(f2);

  int result;
  while ((result = read_line_pair(f1, f2)) == 1) {
    ;
  }

  fclose(f1);
  fclose(f2);
}
```

Output

```
6.6 6.6 6.6 6.6 6.6 
1.1 0.9 
Error(Number 5 != Number 6)
```